# How to get value from another method

Tags: android, methods, parameters

Such as,

> public void ShowConventView2(){
>
> ```
>      setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>      String usr = "happy"; }
> ```

How to pass value of usr to ShowConventView3 ? if ShowConventView3 is

> public void ShowConventView3(){
>
> ```
>      setContentView(R.layout.second);
>
>      TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>
>      txt.setText(usr); }
> ```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could make it a global variable

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ShowConventView2() {
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     String usr = "happy";
     ShowConventView3(usr);
}

public void ShowConventView3(String text){
     setContentView(R.layout.second);
     TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     txt.setText(text); 
}
```